# Manual Uninstall of Wubi Failed, Stuck and Cannot Reinstall

Tags: wubi, uninstall, re-installation

I want to reinstall Wubi on Windows 7 (ASUS 1215N). I followed the uninstall instructions at [this Ubuntu Wiki page](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/WubiGuide#Uninstallation).

I get this error message:

```
Error executing command
>>command=C:\windows\System32\bcdedit.exe /delete
(1ed40def-63a5-11f5-88ad-a65437514e86) /f
>>retval=1
specified entry
The system cannot find the file specified

>>stdout=
```

There is a log file that shows a traceback of python programs in `lib/wubi`.

What can I do now to get rid of the vestiges of my previous Wubi so I can reinstall?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! The Ubuntu Wiki page you linked to has multiple sets of uninstallation instructions (via the Control Panel, `Uninistall-Ubuntu.exe`, or manually). Can you clarify exactly which set of steps you took? Thanks!

Comment: This question should instead be filed as a bug report, and [as such](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1317/what-to-do-with-questions-that-describe-known-bugs/) is off-topic, thanks! [Instructions here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you just want to get rid of the "Ubuntu" entry in the bootloader. To do this, press Windows Key(Super) + R and type in msconfig. Press enter. Go to the boot tab and highlight the wubi entry. Click delete. Restart the computer. It should boot to Windows without giving you the Ubuntu option.

Comment: the bootloader only shows window 7 -- the error message i typed comes up when i execute uninstall

Comment: When you launch wubi.exe does it give you a message stating that a previous installation was detected and an uninstall button?

Comment: And, as WarriorIng said, please clarify what uninstallation method you are using.

Comment: have tried two: the manual way at the url i gave and the uninstall that is kept by windows -- the error message is, of course, from the latter

Comment: Does wubi.exe give you the uninstall option?

Comment: have done that as well with the same outcome

Comment: What outcome? Does it give you a dialog box, open up cmd, what?

Comment: Did you try to uninstall, the uninstall filed, but it got far enough to get rid of the bootloader entry? Did it tell you it uninstalled sucsessfully? What uninstallation method did you use? I need more information.

Comment: began this a week ago and was diverted -- i may have just started

Comment: I apologize, but that made no sense.

Comment: Was this ever resolved ? If so, can you add in the solution as an answer please.